# WebRequest using SSL

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ftp, webrequest

I have the following code to retrieve a file using FTP (which works fine).

```
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(svrPath);

            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uname, passw);

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            using (StreamWriter destination = new StreamWriter(destinationFile))
            {
                destination.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                destination.Flush();
            }
```

However, when I try to do this using SSL, I am unable to access the file, as follows:

```
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(svrPath);

            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;

            // The following line causes the download to fail
            request.EnableSsl = true;

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uname, passw);

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            using (StreamWriter destination = new StreamWriter(destinationFile))
            {
                destination.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                destination.Flush();
            }
```

Can anyone tell me why the latter would not work?

EDIT:

I get the following exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.
```

Comment: What is the error number/message?

Comment: Sorry - I've edited my question

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the ftp using ssl with any other application to confirm it has ssl enabled ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where do you validate the SSL certificate?  Doing SSL over an FTP connection isn't quite as simple as setting the `.EnableSsl` property.  You need to provide a certificate validation method.  See [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/authentication/article.php/c15051) for the C# code to do what you want.  Also, someone copied and pasted their whole FTP class in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) if you need a more detailed implementation.

Just to quickly get you up and running quickly, test with this:

```
if (request.EnableSsl) ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
```

and then later:

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
 return true; // Read the links provided above for real implementation
}
```

Comment: any way to do this on a case-by-case basis?  That seems to be global.

Answer (score -3):

Try this
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(svrPath);